# tr is breaking utf-8 codification

Tags: bash, character, tr

I have this input:

> i would like to know; the price of travel San_Sebastián Gerona exit the fourteenth of february two thousand four? and if possible travel in intercity!
>
> San_Sebastián

And I expect the same but without ".,/*¡?;¿!", so I have decided to do a tr -d. My sourprise is that when I do:

```
cat log | tr -d ".,/*¡?;¿!" >> output.log
```

I see this:

```
 i would like to know the price of travel San_Sebasti<C3>n Gerona exit
 the fourteenth of february two thousand four and if possible travel in
 intercity
```

`San_Sebasti<C3>n`

It has broken all the accents in the text but don't know why

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/228570/74329

Answer (score 1):

The command tr breaks accented characters because it does not understand multibyte characters (all accented chars are multibyte chars in utf-8).

You can use sed (which does interpret multibyte characters just fine):

```
cat log | sed 's#[.,/*¡?;¿!]##g' >> output.log
```

Comment: Square brackets missing. Also, it only works under `*.UTF-8` locale.

Comment: I finally putted this:

`sed "s/[.,/*¡!?¿;]//g"`

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -CSAD -pe 'tr=.,/*?;!¿¡==d' < log >> output.log
```

Perl's `tr///` works similarly to `tr`, I used `=` instead of `/` to avoid backslashing.

`-C` turns on utf-8 for stdin, stdout, and stderr (S), arguments (A), and input + output streams (D). Only S is needed in this particular case.